# KMDF IOCTL communication with nonpnp driver?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, ioctl

I am trying to write a windows non-pnp kernel mode software driver which should communicate bidirectional with my user mode app (user sends request and driver responds). The problem is that I can't find examples or documentations - the msdn sample drivers are far to compilcated - how to handle IOCTL requests with non-pnp drivers.

I wasted a couple days on research and couldn't get it to work. I just wanted to ask if this kind of communication is even the recommended one and would appreciate everything which would help me finish my project, like understandable documentation or simple sample drivers.

Comment: As far as I know, it makes no difference whether it's a PNP or non-PNP driver.  You just implement DispatchDeviceControl().

Comment: What I have read so far is the `DispatchDeviceControl()` function provided by the framework because I don't use WDM but the WDF framework.

Comment: OK, according to the documentation the WDF framework has a EvtIoDeviceControl() callback for handling IOCTL requests.  As far as I can see, it still doesn't make any difference whether it is a PNP driver or not.  Can you clarify why you think it should?

Comment: I was quite unsure about it just because I couldn't find an example using a non-PNP driver. I'm glad to here that it shouldn't make a differnce.